# Latextools can't find added PATH when starting sublime from unity launcher

Tags: linux, path, latex, sublimetext3

I have Ubuntu 16.04, sublime text 3 and sublime package latextools on my computer for Latex editing. I installed Latexlive and added the bin path to system `PATH`.

When I started sublime with `subl` from the terminal and compile a `.tex` file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> using latextools, the compilation worked fine. But when I locked the sublime icon on the side launcher and start sublime from launcher, then the compilation went wrong:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... 

COULD NOT COMPILE!

Attempted command:latexmk -cd -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 test.tex
Build engine: Traditional Builder
```

I think when I start sublime from launcher, it can't find my added system `PATH` where I installed latexlive. So how can I fix this problem?